# Manner of energy exchange between an accelerating charge and the fields it produce

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

The fields produced by a charged particle in accelerated motion produces an [electric and magnetic field given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Field_computation) $${\vec E}(\vec r,t)=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left[\frac{(\hat{n}-{\vec \beta})}{\gamma^2(1-{\vec\beta}\cdot\hat{n})^3R^2}+\frac{\hat{n}\times\left[(\hat{n}-\vec\beta)\times{\dot{\vec\beta}}\right]}{c(1-{\vec\beta}\cdot\hat{n})^3R}\right]_{\rm ret}={\vec E}_{v}+{\vec E}_a.\\
{\vec B}_{v}=\hat{n}_{\rm ret}\times{\vec E}_v,~{\vec B}_{a}=\hat{n}_{\rm ret}\times{\vec E}_a$$ where ${\vec E}_{v}, {\vec B}_{v}$ and ${\vec E}_a, {\vec B}_{a}$ are called velocity and acceleration fields, respectively.

Let me quotes a few lineas from Griffiths:

> ... the velocity felds do carry energy—they just don’t transport it out to infnity. As the particle accelerates and decelerates, energy is exchanged between it and the velocity felds, at the same time as energy is irretrievably radiated away by the acceleration felds.

I want to understand this statement.

Because the acceleration field carries energy off to infinity while the velocity field does not, the energy carried by the acceleration field is irretrievably lost. However, there is something I do not understand.

He seems to be saying that there can be an exchange of energy **from** the charge **to** the velocity field and vice-versa. The energy transfer is back-and-forth in this case.  However, there is no such back-and-forth of energy between the charge and the acceleration field. There can only be a one-way transfer of energy from the charge to the acceleration field but **not** from the acceleration field back to the charge. Why is this so? How can we understand this?

Comment: can you give a link fot the context where these formulae are defined ?

Comment: the energy is irretrievably lost because it becomes an electromagnetic wave, the great discovery of Maxwell

Comment: @annav https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Field_computation   These fields are calculated from Lienard-Wiechart potentials.

Comment: I wrote a paper on this: Tracking the radiation reaction energy when charged bodies accelerate, AMERICAN JOURNAL OF PHYSICS 83 (2015) 703-710; see also https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1349

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity field is a local field "attached" to the particle. Since it never really leaves, you can think of a generalized "dressed" particle consisting of the particle itself and its local field. The energy *within* this "dressed" particle can be converted between the velocity field and the kinetic energy of the particle. But the more important thing is that the dressed particle is losing energy to the acceleration field.

The acceleration field is a radiative field that escapes to infinity. This energy is truly lost to the system. Quite literally, the accelerating charge is generating light, and this light carries energy away.

However, this energy is not *irreversibly* lost -- this only appears to be the case due to the boundary conditions of this particular problem. It is certainly possible for *incoming* radiation to interact with the charged particle. To give a concrete example, supposed we had two widely separated accelerating charges. Then the acceleration field of particle 1 will cause energy to leave from particle 1. But some of this acceleration field can interact with particle 2 and impart energy to it.

Comment: It is not clear why a back a forth of energy goes on between the particle and velocity field but the energy flow is only one-way between the particle and the acceleration field.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 The energy in the acceleration field is radiated to infinity. There is only a one-way exchange because of the boundary conditions: there is no incoming acceleration field. If there was, some energy would go from the acceleration field to the particle.

Comment: In the far zone, the radiation is due to time derivatives of multipole moments of the source. By the conservation of charge, the leading order multipole moment -- the monopole moment, or charge -- is conserved, so $\dot{Q}=0$. Therefore the leading order time-dependent multipole moment is the dipole, $p\sim Qr$. The vector potential is proportional to a time derivative, $A\sim \dot{p}\sim Q v$, and the electric field is a time derivative of the vector potential, $E\sim \dot{A} \sim Q a$. This just gives you a heuristic derivation of why the acceleration is related to radiation.

Comment: Here's an article on multipole radiation if you want to know more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_radiation